# To pass data from backend to frontend?

Tags: python, mongodb, cherrypy

I am working on a simple web app in python, where I have populated a MongoDB database and trying to send data from its backend to frontend and display the data. However, somehow i have managed to achieve the getting the data part from the MongoDB and I am not able to retrieve it to frontend and display on dom.
Have googled more than enough, about links and tutorials. Any point to the right direction will also be very helpful.
Here is my backend code.

```
    import cherrypy
import os.path
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from bson import BSON
from bson import json_util

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 3000})
cherrypy.engine.restart()

data = []


class Dbextractor(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return open('index.html')

    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def toshow(self):
        i = 0
        client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
        admin = client.stock_data
        cursor = admin.col.find({})
        for document in cursor:
            # print(document['SC_NAME'])
            data.append(document)
# data.update({i: {json.dumps(document, default=json_util.default)}})
# i = i+1
        return data[0]

    @cherrypy.expose
    def shutdown(self):
        cherrypy.engine.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        },
        '/toshow': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'json')],
        }

    }
    webapp = Dbextractor()
    cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

this is my javascript which I am trying to use.

```
     var request = new Request({
  url: '/toshow',
  method: 'GET'
});
fetch(request).then(function (value) {
    console.log(value)
});
```

The data returning in the python is returning a list with dict content in it.

Comment: You already have a handler returning data. Just query GET /toshow from your JS using Fetch API for example

Comment: yes i am trying, however, i tried directly returning the html file from return with data in it, was trying using mako as a renderer but this was making my code messy

Comment: tried, saying path not found

Comment: `  var request = new Request({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/toshow',
  method: 'GET'
});
fetch(request).then(function (value) {
    console.log(value[0])
});`

Comment: You are missing `http://`

Comment: `let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/toshow')` or use just `/toshow` if you do request from the same domain.

Comment: no sir, i didnt miss 'http' the SO have converted it to link. :-(

Comment: let me reframe my quest

Comment: Thanks it helped, do write the answer in answer section so that i can upvote it..thanks a lot